# Sort Multidimensional Array in PHP based on date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [date] => 15.12.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [date] => 19.12.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [date] => 15.11.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )
)
```

What I would like to do is sort the items into high-to-low order in the first dimension based on the date value in the second dimension. I can use strtotime() on the [date] field and produce a unix timestamp (please note, these dates are in Australian format and not US. The server produces the correct timestamp).

I'm aware that I can use arsort() to arrange this array, but I'm not sure how to do it based on the value of a second dimension array key.

I need the array to look like this:

```
  Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [date] => 19.12.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [date] => 15.12.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [date] => 15.11.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )
)
```

How can I best achieve this in PHP?

I've tried various arrangements of the following to no avail:

```
arsort($items, strtotime(['date']))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Answer (score 1):

You should use `usort`

In your case:

```
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your $array is declared that way:

```
$my_array = array(
              array(
                'id'=>4,
                'date'=>'19.12.2014',
                'archived'=>0),
              array(
                 'id'=>3,
                 'date'=>'15.12.2014',
                 'archived'=>0),
              array(
                 'id'=>6,
                 'date'=>'15.11.2014',
                 'archived'=>0));
```

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function with a closure function as follows

```
usort($my_array, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
});
```

`usort` will sort your array "in place", means that no copy of array will be returned but original array is sorted.
Moreover, I've used [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to make order between dates as a starting dates are represent as strings and not in "real date" format.

Moreover keep in mind that

> Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than
>   just reordering the keys.

Execution test

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [date] => 15.11.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [date] => 15.12.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [date] => 19.12.2014
            [archived] => 0
        )
)
```